# How to listen for new chat messages on Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, background, task, aidl

I'm writing a small chat client for android. So the behaviour I want is, that my application is listening in the background for new messages and shows them in the notification area (only the icon of my app). Listening for incoming messages should be a really long term thing - maybe over days after closing the ui thread

My question is: How to do it? Should I have a service with it's own process? should I start an AsyncTask for the Listener? Or are there much better ways to do it? And if I use a new Service Process, do I need to use AIDL?

Answer (score 2):

> How to do it?

Have your chat server [use GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to push chat messages to the device.

> Should I have a service with it's own process?

No.

First, it would not need to be in its own process.

Second, this would require you keep the service running all of the time, which many users dislike.

Third, this would require you to keep the device powered on all of the time with the WiFi radio powered on all of the time, which users will not appreciate. The exception: if you are running on a device supporting mobile data (e.g., a phone), and you are very very careful, you can maintain an open socket connection to a server while the device is asleep. This is difficult to get working properly.

> should I start an AsyncTask for the Listener?

Probably not.

> Or are there much better ways to do it?

Have your chat server [use GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to push chat messages to the device.

Or, possibly, change your chat server to work on a queuing model, so you can poll periodically (on a user-configurable interval) to pick up available messages.

> And if I use a new Service Process, do I need to use AIDL?

No.

Comment: Thank you :) looks very interesting, but I need to use XMPP.